# Samsung Smart TV App development - Show notification on screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to develop an application on samsung smart tv which can display notification while you are watching TV. a notification will contain information about soccer games, twitter messages (can send a message to the tv using twitter) and more...

The smart TV app will get information from a web server, I thought of using Publish/Subscribe model :

- I created an MQTT Broker using NodeJS mosca module.
- I created two scripts which will be the publishers. they will get information from web APIs and publish them under topics to the broker.
- The broker sends new messages for each topic to all the subscribed clients, typically the smart tv app.

You can find this project in [Github](https://github.com/soufi/screenpusher) (don't hesitate to contribute if you are interested).

I have never developed an app for smart TVs, so I wanted to know :

- Is there a function in Samsung SDK for smart TVs that allows to show notifications on the top of the screen ?
- How can I run the app on background ?

The perfect thing in my case would be a Web API for the Smart TV. So that I can call services to show notifications for example or other stuff ...

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developing app for samsung smart tv is simple if you are well versed about html5,css,jquery.

you can show notification by sending ajax call after regular interval(i am not stressing on this part assuming that you know about ajax and jquery)

Now coming to your main question about displaying notification on top of screen and running app in background this can only be achieved in samsung smart TV by making ticker parameter vaue y in config.xml

```
<ticker itemtype='boolean'>y</ticker>
```

This will allow you to run app in ticker mode as well as in background. please go though [samsungdforum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?FolderName=tec00124&FileName=index.html).
Note : The Ticker apps are allowed only for US and Korean market.

Comment: Hi @abhi, I am sorry but I can't find these services that you're talking about. 
I am now trying **CAPH simple apps** to see if I can find something that fits my need [here](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=tec00169&FileName=index.html).

Another question, can I use my own television to test ticker app ?

Comment: Yes you can but it depends where do you live, again Europe is not place where it will work

Comment: Ok then I can't use it ... too bad ... you think there is another solution to do what I want to ? 
and another question : is it possible to include Libraries like jQuery in a javascript smart tv app ? I suppose that it is possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible to include jquery in smart tv app